# Why can't NestJS resolve the dynamic module options parameter I added as a provider?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, nest-dynamic-modules

I made a dynamic module named `AuthModule` copied from Nest's documentation. I changed it so I could supply different Auth0 tenant credentials to the `Auth0Service` for every module that imports it. The configuration parameter in the provider array of the Auth. module is unresolved in the importing/calling module. The error appears when I run `npm run start`. I called `Auth0`'s register method in the calling module (`Users`) imports array. I have added `Auth`'s options parameter to its array of providers. When I run `npm start`, I get an error saying Nest cannot resolve the dependency AUTH0_CONFIG.

`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the Auth0Service (?)...Please make sure that the argument AUTH0_CONFIG at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.`

Exporting the options parameter from `Auth0` allows my app to run. The problem is that when I make any Axios request in the `Auth0Service` thru `UsersModule`, I get a 409 error. I get the 409 error even from Auth0 API endpoints that do not return a 409 error according to Auth0 documentation.

The Auth0 module is globally scoped and imported by UsersModule. Auth0's register method returns itself dynamic module:

```
@Global()
@Module({})
export class AuthModule {
  public static register(auth0Params: Auth0Params): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: AuthModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: AUTH0_CONFIG, useValue: auth0Params },
        Auth0Service,
      ],
      exports: [AuthService],
    };
  }
}
```

This is how I imported the `AuthModule` into `UsersModule`:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, UserRepository]),
    HttpModule,
    AuthModule.register({
      domain: process.env.DOMAIN,
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [UserService, UserResolver, Auth0Service],
  exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

How do I solve this? What should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you're importing the dynamic module `AuthModule.register` into `UserModule`, which exports the provider `Auth0Service`, I don't see any reason to register that provider again in `UserModule`.

When you do so, you must have to register all the dependencies of `Auth0Service` again into `UserModule`, but you can't do that as that `AUTH0_CONFIG` is private to `AuthModule`.

To solve this, just drop the `Auth0Service` from `providers` array of `UserModule`.

When we import some module, we're importing all the providers that that module registers and exports.